# Is it *really* worth to use integer over varchar for a set of data?

Tags: sql, database, optimization

For example if I have a table User, I want to store gender or sex, I'll add a column like `sex`.

Is it really worth to use an integer and then map it in my favorite programming language?

Like `1 => 'Male'` and `2 => 'Female'`

Is there any performance reason to do that?

Or could I safely use a varchar which *more* meaning with 'female' or 'male' almost like I was using mysql `ENUM` ?

**Edit**: I here and there that it is sometimes better, sometimes it doesn't matter, so I more looking for benchmark or something over a "it is better" answer.

I mean I think using varchar is actually more meaningfull than an integer, and I would use an integer only if performance are more than 0.3% or something.

Comment: Do you have a particular RDBMS in mind? The detail will be implementation dependant.

Comment: As far as I understand it in MySQL check constraints are broken so you wouldn't be able to enforce valid genders with the string approach (unless the strings mapped to another FK table anyway). Obviously takes up a bit more space than `int` too as well as more complex comparison rules (I doubt you would index this column anyway as insufficiently selective)

Comment: I took the trouble to benchmark it on my local server and the results were very surprising, the `CHAR(1)` is the fastest. Look at my updated answer

Comment: My benchmark was incorrect. See my updated answer. The `TINYINT` is actually fastest. Sorry for such a stupid mistake ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Ortiginal Answer:*
I would suggest storing it in a `CHAR(1)` column as `M` or `F`
It is expressive enough for the specific purpose AND has the speed benefit of being a single character comparison

**Update 4 (fixed benchmark):**
All *previous benchmarks had a fatal flaw* that one (the `CHAR(1)`) table was `MyISAM` and all other were `InnoDB`. So I recreated the database with all tables using the `MyISAM` and the results make much more sense now.

The error creeped in as I used the MySQLWorkbench's wizard to create the tables and forgot to change the database engine in the other tables and it defaulted to `InnoDB` (I have MySQL 5.5)

So the corrected results are as follows, (I have removed all my previous benchmarks as they were invalid) :

```
// select queries
$query['char'] = "select count(*) from test_table where gender = 'M'";
$query['char_lower'] = "select count(*) from test_table where LOWER(gender) = 'm'";
$query['varchar'] = "select count(*) from test_table_2 where gender = 'Male'";
$query['varchar_lower'] = "select count(*) from test_table_2 where LOWER(gender) = 'male'";
$query['tinyint'] = "select count(*) from test_table_3 where gender = 1";

// benchmark result
array
  'char' => float 0.35457420349121
  'char_lower' => float 0.44702696800232
  'varchar' => float 0.50844311714172
  'varchar_lower' => float 0.64412498474121
  'tinyint' => float 0.26296806335449
```

**New Conclusion :** `TINYINT` Is fastest. But my recommendation would be still yo use `CHAR(1)` as it would be easier for future developers to understand the database.

If you do use `TINYINT`, my recommendation would be name the column `ismale` instead of `sex` and store `0 => Female` and `1 => male` thus making it a little more easy to understand in raw database.

*The table structure* for benchmark is this:

```
CREATE TABLE `test_table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `gender` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM
```

Only the type of the gender column is different in the 3 tables, the types are:

```
CHAR(1), VARCHAR(6), TINYINT
```

All 3 tables have `10000` entries.

Comment: Interesting results. Are they consistently reproducible? Also what if you try `TINYINT`?

Comment: @MartinSmith I have run this over 10 times and the results are similar. I was surprised too. I will try it with a `TIYINT` field and update my results

Comment: @MartinSmith I have Updated my benchmark results, with a table with `TINYINT` column. Still `CHAR(1)` is the winner. I have also summarized my benchmark results at the beginning of my post. Have a look. And the results are consistent over multiple benchmark runs.

Comment: @MartinSmith The results were incorrect. I used different storage engines for tables. Please see my updated answer it makes more sense now that `TINYINT` is fastest. We all make stupid mistakes ;-)

Comment: Still I already +1ed you for taking the time to benchmark anyway as the OP indicates they want to know the actual performance differential to expect.

Comment: It makes the good compromise I was looking for meaning & performance, I'm still thinking that we're no more in the 80' and such storage optimisation are only applicable to big database, mine is about 300,000 registered users which is good but may not be enough to prevent meaning for performance reasons. Obviously, gender is such a common case, but there are case where that a bit more obscure to work with, such as statuses or something, however I agree that a table with a FK would be the best solution, but for immutable data it may not be needed (except to enforce integrity)

Comment: Is there a difference if we used ENUM('m','f') as opposed to CHAR(1)?

Answer (score 18):

If this is for some homebrew website or application that will serve 10 people, then do whatever you want, performance won't make a difference.

If this is for something *real* then skip rolling your own implementation of gender and follow the [ISO standard for sex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_5218). Or at least adhere to standards wherever they exist (thanks Joe Celko!)

```
0 = not known
1 = male
2 = female
9 = not applicable
```

### Always rightsize your data type

- Disk space savings:
  At my last job, the pedantic people in charge of designing tables created a column as decimal with 0 precision because it should only be N digits. The difference in storage cost between that and a whole number data type was 1 or 2 bytes. However, as this table was *very* large the aggregate cost savings of having the smaller data type was measure in gigabytes on the table alone.
- Access savings: 
  A second cost that most don't think about is the cost to read information from disk or to keep data in memory. In SQL Server, data is stored in 8K pages. If you are using fat data types, it will take more reads to get data off disk and then you can store subsequently fewer data pages in memory. **Pulling data off of disk is where you will incur the biggest performance cost. If you want to speed up things that use a database, don't bone the physical implementation.**

Implement as the smallest allowable type in your system that will cover the problem domain. For something like gender, use a tinyint ([MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html), [SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx)) or number(5,0) in [Oracle](http://www.jlcomp.demon.co.uk/faq/num_size.html) and you'll be spending 1 bye of storage for each gender.

### Internationlization

M = Male, F = Female, that seems obvious. ¿Verdad? Aqui, nosotros hablamos español. And that's about as far as my Spanish caries me, but my point is that if you ever need to be multi-lingual, 1 will serve males, gentes, mannlich, masculin, etc. M or Male will only serve an English speaking audience. Further more, then you run into weird presentation logic of "We need to translate everything unless it's going to $culture." It is a far cleaner design to have presentation logic is the UI and keep it out of the database.

Comment: Didn't know about this standard, but definitively worth to know it :)

Comment: Example of i18n, in Irish, women is Mná and men is Fir. Very confusing for tourists when written on bathroom stalls

Answer (score 3):

It will be much faster than doing a string comparison, if you are doing any `SELECTS` on it.

```
SELECT * FROM User WHERE Gender = 'female'
```

*Example:*

Say I have `female` as a string. Its 6 characters long. So it has to do a comparison 6 times for every record, and that is using strict casing - it gets more costly to do case insensitive.

Now say I have `123456` as an int. Its one value, not 6 to compare, even though the human readable string is 6 characters long.

*Aside*

Ideally, `Male` and `Female` would be another table and your `User` table would have a FK to that table.

Answer (score 3):

The benefit of storing as `varchar` is that the data can mostly speak for itself - however, it ends there and only manifests itself in queries against the raw data which will usually be done by a developer that knows the system anyway (exposing data querying functionality to users or others would generally use an application layer, which means you *could* format it as desired regardless.) And this data is OK to display, but consider having to constantly parse it!

As for storing as an integer, it is a little obfuscated, but so long as it is in the data specification and mappings laid out clearly, then you reap benefits of using the data more productively in your application (using a mapping of map an `integer` to an `enum` is a one off thing and exposes a more usable type in terms or branching logic, removing string parsing.) It will also be more efficient than storing strings.

There is of course the route of storing 'options' in a dedicated table and having other table fields reference it, but what I've found in many projects is that this is far from ideal in terms of utilisation, unless still using mappable types - which then the table only serves to obscure things a little more, potentially.

Answer (score 3):

Integer are much faster than doing string comparison, but I think your better of using chars 'M' or 'F'. If people dump the table they'll know exactly what you intended and its better than maintaining a join table. Unless we're going to be running across new sexes soon.

Comment: @MikeSanchez Such a prophetic sentence.  Is Praveen perhaps a prophet?

Answer (score 2):

it depends.. but generally yes.

ints take up less space on disk.

ints compare faster

ints travel over the network faster (smaller)

so if it is one row only, and you query it once a day - you'll never notice, but in general, you will benefit.

Comment: "ints compare faster" I don't disagree but any specific figures on this? (applies to 3/5 answers but can't be bothered to comment on all)

Comment: well.. an int is a single value in memory, so when you compare one single value to another, then that is one equality to check... strings are one value per character, plus some overhead to find out how many characters there are in this particular string...  so multiple checks.

Comment: Plus the strings compare under collation rules which should be more complex anyway. As I said I don't disagree but the only actual figures posted so far anywhere in any of the answers indicate that for some reason in practice `char(1)` out performs `int` (Edit: Just seen the edit to that answer which gives revised results!)

Answer (score 2):

This is a non-brainer: use [ISO 5218](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_5218) values. Why reinvent the wheel and make your locale-specific and less portable?

Because the set of values is small and stable, you can get away with using a `CHECK` constraint... oops, I mean, for MySQL create a lookup table with a foreign key!