# Can SQL Queries replace boolean value with specific value(as we define dynamically) when we use SELECT statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I just have an odd question. I know it may be funny but I just have a curiosity about this.
Here is my question in detail:

Suppose there is a column in database named 'gender' that has boolean value i.e. either 0 or 1. 0=Male and 1=Female.
Now when we display data of a form that has this type of field, we have to do code, that `(gender=0)?Male:Female.`

Now I just want to know if sql provide any way, where automatically when a Record Set is generated, all gender value is replaced by Male or Female automatically. i.e. no need of this one line code?

Comment: Look at the [case](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/case.php) statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

aside from case/decode which others have shown, in 11gR1 onwards we can have a virtual Column.

```
SQL> create table test(name varchar2(20), gender number(1));

Table created.

SQL> insert into test values ('Paul', 0);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test values ('Vicky', 1);

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> alter table test add (gender_str varchar2(6) generated always as (case gender when 0 then 'Male' when 1 then 'Female' end));

Table altered.

SQL> select * from test;

NAME                                         GENDER GENDER
-------------------- ------------------------------ ------
Paul                                              0 Male
Vicky                                             1 Female
```

you can index virtual columns too if you so desire.

Answer (score 5):

I'd use [decode](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm):

```
select decode(gender,0,'Male','Female') from your_table;
```

Comment: Just want to mention that DECODE is a function, where CASE is part of the SQL standard, so DECODE is not vendor agnostic, while CASE is vendor agnostic.  The OP specified Oracle, so either one would work for him, but for others who might see this, if cross-vendor support is a concern, use CASE instead.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `case` statement for that, like this:

```
select
 case gender when 0 then 'Male' when 1 then 'Female' end
from
 ...
```

If gender is neither 0 nor 1, you'll get a null in that column.

Answer (score 2):

You could also look at codifying this logic into a [Virtual column](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/virtual-columns-11gr1.php) as they call them in Oracle. SQL Server folks would know them as computed columns.

The advantage of this approach, is that existing logic will continue to write to your gender field (so no rewrite needed) but new apps can pull from the `genderEnglishName` field.

The "right" answer in my mind is to obey the standard for sex, [ISO 5218](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_5218). I would retain the gender field as an integer, assign the correct translations and leave the interpretation logic up to the presentation layer in case you ever need to work with [internationalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539001/is-it-really-worth-to-use-integer-over-varchar-for-a-set-of-data/7539495#7539495).

Answer (score 1):

You could use `CASE WHEN` to assing your own values :)

```
Case when column = true 
then myvalue 
else true End
```

Looking at your exact query values: And I believe there's only 0 and 1, so you only need **one `When`** :))

```
-- your code
Case when Gender = 0 
Then 'Male'
Else 'Female'
End 
-- rest of your code
```